# How to write deduction guidelines for aliases of aggregate templates?

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization, template-aliases, deduction-guide

With C++20, it is possible to have deduction guidelines generated for an alias template (See section "Deduction for alias templates" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). Yet, I could not make them work with aggregate initialization syntax. It looks like in this case the deduction guidelines for the alias is not generated.

See this example:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t N>
using mytype = std::array<int, N>;

// Deduction guideline ???

int main() {
    // mytype error_object = {1, 4, 7}; // ERROR
    mytype<3> object = {1, 4, 7}; // OK, but I have to manually specify the size.
    return object[0];
}
```

I have tried writing deduction guidelines but I get compiler errors every time.

```
template <typename T, typename ... U>
mytype(T, U...) -> mytype<1+sizeof...(U)>; // Compiler error
```

and any other guideline I could think of.

Is it even possible to have the size of the array alias automatically deduced?

I am using GCC 10.2

Comment: From what I read, deduction guide for alias use deduction guide of source with some adjustment, I don't see that writing deduction guide for alias is allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it even possible to have the size of the array alias automatically deduced?

I believe that it should be possible with a standard-conforming implementation. You needn't (and can't) add any more guides.

However, GCC implements [a different set of rules](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1a291106384cabc73da0bc0f457b1cd3a4015970/gcc/cp/pt.c#L28131-L28141) than what the standard specifies:

> ```
> This implementation differs from [the specification] in two significant ways:
>
> 1) We include all template parameters of A, not just some.
> 2) The added constraint is same_type instead of deducible.
> ```

The implementer believed that "this simplification should have the same effect for real uses". But apparently this is not the case: this implementation fails to work in your case and [ICEs in some other cases](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR93295).

---

For the reference, I'll try to follow the standard and show how the guide for `mytype` is generated.

We have this alias template declaration (the alias template is called `A` in the standard):

```
template <size_t N>
using mytype = std::array<int, N>;
```

and this deduction guide from the standard library ([[array.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/array.cons)):

```
template<class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

First, a function template (called `f` in the standard) is generated from the deduction guide ([[over.match.class.deduct]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1)):

```
template<class T, class... U>
auto f(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

Then, per [[over.match.class.deduct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2.sentence-3):

> the template arguments of the return type of `f` are deduced from the *defining-type-id* of `A` according to the process in [temp.deduct.type] with the exception that deduction does not fail if not all template arguments are deduced.

That is, we deduce the template arguments in `array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>` from `std::array<int, N>`. In this process, `T` is deduced to be `int`; `U` is not deducible, so it is left as-is.

The result of deduction is substituted into the function template, resulting in:

```
template<class T, class... U>
auto g(int, U...) -> array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

Then, we generate a function template `f'`. `f'` has the same return type and function parameter types as `g`. (If `f` has special properties, they are inherited by `f'`.) But notably, the template parameter list of `f'` consists of ([[over.match.class.deduct]/(2.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2.2.sentence-1), emphasis mine):

> all the template parameters of `A` (including their default template arguments) **that appear in the above deductions** or (recursively) in their default template arguments, followed by the template parameters of `f` **that were not deduced** (including their default template arguments), otherwise `f'` is not a function template.

Since `N` does not appear in the deduction, it is not included in the template parameter list (*this is where GCC differs from the standard*).

Additionally, `f'` has a constraint ([[over.match.class.deduct]/(2.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2.3.sentence-1)):

> that is satisfied if and only if the arguments of `A` are deducible (see below) from the return type.

Therefore, according to the standard, the generated function template looks like:

```
template<class... U>
  requires deducible<array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>>
auto f'(int, U...) -> array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

Clearly, the size can be deduced as `1 + sizeof...(U)` according to this guide.

In the next step, let's see how `deducible` is defined.

[[over.match.class.deduct]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#3):

> The arguments of a template `A` are said to be deducible from a type `T` if, given a class template
>
> ```
> template <typename> class AA;
> ```
>
> with a single partial specialization whose template parameter list is that of `A` and whose template argument list is a specialization of `A` with the template argument list of `A` ([temp.dep.type]), `AA<T>` matches the partial specialization.

In our case, the partial specialization would be:

```
 template <size_t N> class AA<mytype<N>> {};
```

So `deducible` can be declared as:

```
 template <class T> concept deducible = requires { sizeof(AA<T>); };
```

Since `N` is deducible from `1 + sizeof...(U)`, `array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>` is always a valid match for `mytype<N>` (a.k.a. `std::arrray<int, N>`), and thus the constraint `deducible<array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>>` is always satisfied.

Therefore, according to the standard, the generated guide is viable and can deduce the size.

In comparison, GCC generates:

```
template<class... U, size_t N>
  requires same_type<array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>, mytype<N>>
auto f_(int, U...) -> array<int, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

... which is not able to deduce `N`.