# Why can't GCC compiler deduce one of the template parameter from std::array in alias template form

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, template-aliases, ctad

In C++20, alias templates can have implicit deduction guides if it is applied.

Then, I have constructed a simple template alias which is `ints`:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
using ints = std::array<int, N>;
```

but:

```cpp
ints{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

doesn't work, and GCC said:

- error: no matching function for call to `array(int, int, int, int)`
- note:   couldn't deduce template parameter `N`
- note:   mismatched types `std::array<int, N>` and `int`

I don't understand why it fails to compile.

And:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using array_of_4 = std::array<T, 4>;
```

with

```
array_of_4{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

won't work either.

- Is it because `std::array`'s deduction guide is user-provided?
- If the above's answer is not true, then what would be the reason?

---

I have found a similar question regarding this issue: [How to write deduction guidelines for aliases of aggregate templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939408/how-to-write-deduction-guidelines-for-aliases-of-aggregate-templates?rq=1).

This concludes that, in standard, this code should be well-formed. Hence, GCC may have different implementations that prevent this code from compiling.

Comment: The error from clang is: `error: alias template 'ints' requires template arguments; argument deduction only allowed for class templates`.

Comment: clang does not support CTAD for alias templates yet (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ints{1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```
>
> I don't understand why it fails to compile.

You didn't specify the template argument. This works:

```
ints<4>{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

---

> ```
> array_of_4{1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```
>
> won't work either.

Same problem. This works:

```
array_of_4<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

---

> std::array's deduction guide is user-provided?

Yes, it is.

Comment: then, that would defeat the purpose of CTAD in this case? im not sure

Comment: @DesmondGold What do you mean by "defeat the purpose of CTAD"?

Comment: I think the question is why does `std::array a {1, 2, 3, 4};` work, but `ints a {1, 2, 3, 4};` not? The compiler should be able to deduce the type to `std::array<int,4>` in both cases.